# jQuery fadeOut 'inline-block' div fadeIn "inline-block" div

Tags: jquery, fadein, hidden, fadeout, css

Having some trouble getting my jQuery correct. Essentially I want to click on a div, .fadeOut the two other 'inline-block' divs next to it. Keep the 'clicked' div in the same position as well as .fadeIn another (hidden) div. The problem I'm facing is the position of the 'clicked' div moving once the other two fade out & also bringing the other (hidden) div in correctly.
I've followed a few similar posts which suggest altering the positioning of the elements, but it effects the nicely laid out style I have. (please excuse if my post is too long, it's my first time posting!)

I also have no clue as to how im going to bring in the 'hidden' div on the right of the container.

Here is the html:

```
<div id = "maincontainer">
   <div id ="container">
    <div id = "table1">
        <table>
            <tr><td> <img src = "https://si0.twimg.com/profile_images/3109305038/9db39242a7a4024666eb202871ba6bd8_normal.jpeg" /></td></tr>
            <tr><td><p> some text </p></td></tr>
         </table>
         </div>
         <div id = "table2">
        <table>
            <tr><td> <img src = "https://si0.twimg.com/profile_images/3109305038/9db39242a7a4024666eb202871ba6bd8_normal.jpeg" /></td></tr>
            <tr><td><p> some text </p></td></tr>
         </table>
         </div>
         <div id = "table3">
        <table>
            <tr><td> <img src = "https://si0.twimg.com/profile_images/3109305038/9db39242a7a4024666eb202871ba6bd8_normal.jpeg" /></td></tr>
            <tr><td><p> some text </p></td></tr>
         </table>
         </div>
         </div>
         </div>
```

The jQuery:

```
   $(document).ready(function(){
$('#table1').click(function(){
    $('#table2').fadeOut(1000);
    $('#table3').fadeOut(1000); 
});
});
```

The Css:

```
#maincontainer  {
background-color: white;
width: 968px;
height: auto; 
margin: auto;
margin-top: 65px;
margin-bottom: 65px;
}
#container  {
height: 556px;
width: 100%;
margin: auto;
text-align: center;
background-color: blue;
}
#table1 {
height: auto;
margin: auto;
width: 202px;
text-align: center;
display: inline-block;
padding: 45px;
}
#table2 {
height: auto;
margin: auto;
width: 202px;
text-align: center;
display: inline-block;
padding: 45px;
}
#table3 {
height: auto;
margin: auto;
width: 202px;
text-align: center;
display: inline-block;
padding: 45px;
}
```

Demo: [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/arunpjohny/PMP6B/)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Add `float: left;` to all three tables

Demo: [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/arunpjohny/PMP6B/1/)

Side note: Instead of repeating the same styles for `#table1`, `#table2` and `#table3`, you can add a class `table` to all the three elements and add a css rule

```
div.table {
    height: auto;
    margin: auto;
    width: 202px;
    text-align: center;
    display: inline-block;
    padding: 45px;
    float: left;
}
```

Demo: [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/arunpjohny/PMP6B/2/)

Comment: If I put each table into a class, I wont be able to remove the tables which haven't had the image clicked.( I understand html classes & id's =]) Thanks for the float: left help though! It didn't seem to work last time I used it. Is there a way to make the transition of the table floating left more smoother?? Also I have no idea how to go about bringing in a new div to fill the space on the right of the page with information.